# How to create a string that has a numerical value?

Tags: python, string, python-3.5, poker

```
card_value = 'J':11

print(card_value(x),'ack')
print(card_value(y)-11)
```

Basically I am making poker and don’t know how to deal with the J-Ace having their own numbers , while using the value to figure out types of hands.

Comment: you want to create string "J-11" with string var "J" and int var "11" ?

Comment: perhaps a dictionary like `{'J':11}`

Comment: take a look at the basic data structures of Python

Comment: Strings are for humans. Computers do things with numbers. Represent card values (and even suits) as just plain numbers, perhaps 2=2, 3=3,...11=J, 12=Q, etc. And maybe 1=clubs, 2=diamonds, etc. Then do all the coding with numbers, and only translate them to strings for display to a human.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary :

```
my_dict = {'J':11, 'A':10}
```

Then you can retrieve the value :

```
>> my_dict['J']
>> 11
```

Comment: NMDV but never shadow Python built-in names with variables

Comment: @Chris_Rands : Thanks. You're right. Just updated ;)

Comment: If a jack is represented by 11, shouldn't an ace be represented by 14?

Comment: For uniformity, I would put all the possible card values as strings in the dictionary and then always use it to map both the numbered cards and the lettered ones to numeric values (i.e: `{'J':11, 'A':10, '9':9, '8':8, ...}`.